# certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)>” for one particuar domain

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, web-crawler, python-requests

Every request to this one particular domain now ends in an certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)>

I am not sure what caused this.I've been searching for an answer since last night trying to figure out how to fix it, but somehow I cant get it running.

I tried pip uninstall -y certifi && pip install certifi==2015.04.28 but it did not help.

Here is my code:

```
def trade_spider(max_pages):
page = -1

partner_ID = 2
location_ID = 25


already_printed = set()

for page in range(0,20):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.getyourguide.de/s/search.json?q=" + str(Region) +"&page=" + str(page))
    jsondata = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
    format = (jsondata['activities'])
    g_data = format.strip("'<>()[]\"` ").replace('\'', '\"')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(g_data)



    hallo = soup.find_all("article", {"class": "activity-card activity-card-horizontal "})


    for item in hallo:
        headers = item.find_all("h3", {"class": "activity-card-title"})
        for header in headers:
            header_final = header.text.strip()
            if header_final not in already_printed:
                already_printed.add(header_final)



        prices = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
        for price in prices:
            #itemStr += ("\t" + price.text.strip().replace(",","")[2:])
            price_final = price.text.strip().replace(",","")[2:]
            #if itemStr2 not in already_printed:
            #print(itemStr2)
                #already_printed.add(itemStr2)


        deeplinks = item.find_all("a", {"class": "activity-card-link"})
        for t in set(t.get("href") for t in deeplinks):
            #itemStr += "\t" + t
            deeplink_final = t
            if deeplink_final not in already_printed:
                #print(itemStr3)
                already_printed.add(deeplink_final)

        Language = "Deutsch"

        end_final = "Header: " + header_final + " | " + "Price: " + str(price_final) + " | " + "Deeplink: " + deeplink_final + " | " + "PartnerID: " + str(partner_ID) + " | " + "LocationID: " + str(location_ID)+ " | " + "Language: " + Language
        if end_final not in already_printed:
            print(end_final)
            already_printed.add(end_final)
```

trade_spider(int(Spider))

This is the ouput:

```
               Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1240, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1083, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 911, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 854, in send
self.connect()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1237, in connect
server_hostname=server_hostname)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
_context=self)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 747, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Rj/Desktop/ crawling                                        scripts/GetyourGuide_International_Final.py", line 84, in <module>
trade_spider(int(Spider))
File "C:/Users/Raju/Desktop/scripts/GetyourGuide_International_Final.py", line 36, in trade_spider
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.getyourguide.com/s/search.json?q=" + str(Region) +"&page=" + str(page))
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 471, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 581, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in error
result = self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 686, in http_error_302
return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 483, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1283, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1242, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
```

urllib.error.URLError:

Can someone help me out? Any feedback is aprreciated:)

Comment: This kind of error usually indicates a bad server configuration, more exactly the certifacte chain send by the server if faulty.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue using python2 or 3 on ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

I would investigate further by checking if openssl can verify the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.getyourguide.de:443
```

Comment: OK, the certificate is signed by Let's Encrypt Authority X3

Comment: On September 14, 2015, Let's Encrypt issued its first certificate, which was for the domain helloworld.letsencrypt.org. On the same day, ISRG submitted its root program applications to Mozilla, Microsoft, Google and Apple. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt

Comment: I doubt that that CA is in certi==2015.0.28 since it applied only in september

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What should I do now in order to fix the problem? Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: Try installing certifi==2016.08.08

Comment: It tells me "Canot unistall requirement certifi, any other recommendation?